# A die is thrown $n$ times. $X_1$-number of times a number from $\{1,2,3\}$...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

.. $X_2$ number of numbers that fell from $\{4,5\}$, $X_3$ number of $6's$ that fell.

Find $$P\{ X_1=k\mid X_2=m\};0\leq m \leq n.$$

Now, I believe that $X_3$ is completely irrelevant here. What I have trouble with is identifying exactly $m$ numbers from the set within the $n$ rolls and the other respectively as to find the answer... Thoughts ?

Comment: The value of $X_3$ is very relevant. If there were lots of $6$'s, that gave fewr opportunities to get numbers in the range $1$ to $3$. I suggest doing a formal conditional probability calculation.

Comment: Could you maybe help me with this? I have to find the expected value of X(X-1) , and X=G(p) then $EX(X-1)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(k-1)q^{k-1}p$. Why is this the way it is, I understand how to find EX but this is a little foreign for me..

Comment: That is an entirely different problem, so I cannot write the answer as an answer to the current problem. It almost  ertainly has been done a few times on MSE. You can ask a separate question, or make use of the following hint. Left $f(x)=\sum x^k p$,  for $|x|\lt 1$. You can find an explicit formula for $f(x)$, geometric series. Now note that $\sum_2^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-1}p=xf''(x)$.

Comment: I'm aware that the answer as you type is the second derivative of f(x), what I don;t understand is it's relation to X(X-1), this is what confuses me, I would rather not open a new question because I feel this is a small detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Satisfaction of condition $X_2=m$ means that a number in $\{1,2,3,6\}$ was thrown exactly $n-m$ times. What is the probability that $k$ of these times it was a number in $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: That's exactly where I run into trouble the exactly $k$ numbers from a subset of a set.

Comment: The conditional distribution is binomial with parameters $n-m$ and $p=\frac34$. Do you understand that?

Comment: correct me if im wrong: $\binom{n-m}{k} {\frac{3}{4}}^{k} {\frac{1}{4}}^{n-m-k}$

Comment: No correction needed. That is the right answer. More important is of course your understanding of it.

Comment: Would the final answer here be:$\binom{n}{m} {\frac{4}{6}}^{n-m} {\frac{2}{6}}^{m}$ $ \binom{n-m}{k} {\frac{3}{4}}^{k} {\frac{1}{4}}^{n-m-k}$

Comment: or this divided by: $ \binom{n-m}{k} {\frac{3}{4}}^{k} {\frac{1}{4}}^{n-m-k}$

Comment: This is where my last confusions lye.

Comment: The final answer is $\binom{n-m}{k}(\frac34)^{k}(\frac14)^{n-m-k}$. Another route is finding the RHS of equation $P(X_1=k|X_2=m\}=P(X_1=k\wedge X_2=m)/P(X_2=m)$. That is more work and after simplification you will come to the same result. My answer is more direct but requires some insight. That's why I am a bit worried about your understanding.

Comment: I get it now, I was just unsure